# Proof of sum-free set in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Consider $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \backslash\{0\}$ and define $aS=\{as | s \in S \}$. I want to show that $S$ sum-free over $\mathbb{Z}_p \iff aS$ sum-free over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and then I want to show that this $S$ is sum-free over all numbers if $p$ is larger than any element of S.

The first thing I want to show seems simple enough, but I am having trouble making it work in both directions. Here is what I have:
$\implies$: Suppose $S$ sum-free. Then $x,y \in S \implies x+y \notin S$. Consider $ax, ay \in aS$. $ax+ay=a(x+y)$ but $x+y \notin S \implies a(x+y) \notin aS$ by definition.
$\impliedby$: Suppose $aS$ sum-free. Then $ax, ay \in aS \implies ax+ay \notin aS$.

This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to do this proof without repeating the step from the forward direction of turning $ax+ay=a(x+y)$ and then using the definition of $aS$. Is it as simple as doing that?

Finally, in terms of the second thing I want to show, I can express each element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as $s+bp$ for $s \in S, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $x,y \in S$  can be expressed $x+up, y+vp$ and their sum $x+up+y+vp=x+y+(u+v)p$. Now I need to show that this is not in $S$. This is where I am stuck. Using the condition that $p$ is greater than any element of $S$, can the coefficients of $p$ (ie. the values of $u,v$) be assumed $0$? Then the fact that $x+y \notin S$ is seen clearly. However this seems too simple. Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: By ${\bf Z}_p$, you mean the set $\{\,0,1,2,\dots,p-1\,\}$ with addition modulo $p$? If so, then what do you mean by expressing its elements as $a+bp$ for integers $a,b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S \subset \mathbb{Z}$ be a non-empty subset. Then we can reduce $S$ mod $p$ for some prime which I will denote $S_p$. You wanted to show $S_p$ is sum-free in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if $aS_p$ is sum-free in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for any (and all) $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \{0\}$. Your proof is almost right. The point is that since $a \neq 0$, it is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So we can go from $S_p$ to $aS_p$ and back to $S_p$ by multipling by $a^{-1}$.

Suppose $S_p$ is sum free in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then for $ax,ay \in aS_p$ ($x,y \in S_p$), if $a(x+y) \in aS_p$, then by definition, $a(x+y)=az$ for some $z \in S_p$. But inverting $a$ gives $x+y=z \in S_p$ which is a contradiction.

For the converse, we prove the contrapositive statement. Suppose $S_p$ is not sum-free in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then there is some $x,y \in S_p$ with $x+y \in S_p$. Then $ax+ay=a(x+y) \in aS_p$ by definition and so $aS_p$ is not sum-free.

Now for the second part, let's again prove the contrapositive. Working with the original $S \subset \mathbb{Z}$, suppose $S$ is not sum-free (in $\mathbb{Z}$). Then there is $x,y \in S$ so that $x+y \in S$. But clearly, we can take this modulo $p$ so $S_p$ is not sum-free in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It does not matter what $p$ is. Also, we can vary $S$ by multiples of $p$ since that does not change its image $S_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

The converse is false. Take $S=\{2\}$ which is sum-free in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then modulo $2$, $S_2=\{0\}$ which is not sum-free ($0+0=0 \in S$).